# React Native deeplinking and android:launchMode problem

Tags: android, react-native, android-intent, android-activity, mobile

I have been trying deeplinking in a react-native application and trying to directly open a screen inside a navigator. I use `react-native-deep-linking` and `react-navigation` as libraries. Also nested navigators are used. Deeplinking works correctly except I have some problems with the `android:launchMode` property.

This is the results I get for each of the `android:launchMode` options.

- `android:launchMode="standard"` - App opens using the deeplink but opens up an entirely new application.
- `android:launchMode="singleTask"` - App opens using the deeplink. If I open the app using another link. App comes to the foreground but it directs to the previous link.
- `android:launchMode="singleTop"` - App opens using the deeplink but opens up an entirely new application.
- `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` - App opens using the deeplink but opens up an entirely new application.

If I remove the `android:launchMode` property, again the same thing happens as the "standard" mode because it is the default.

What option can I use to resolve this problem? Is there any @override that I can do inside the main activity?

Below is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.VIEW"/>

            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*.myapplive.com" android:pathPrefix="/"/>
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*.myapp.com" android:pathPrefix="/"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if still relevant but may help someone in future.

The reason is that when activity is in any mode other than standard, re-opening the app from the background will not replace the original intent used to launch the app from the killed state. Instead, those new intents will be directed to the `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` method. There, you can call `setIntent(Intent intent)` in order to replace activity's intent with the new one.

You can override this method in your MainActivity. (Note that when overriding this method in React I had to make it `public` and not `protected` as I would usually do in Android. Not sure why yet)

Read more here - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)

Comment: Thanks. I'm not stuck in this anymore. But valuable information.

Comment: How did you solve this problem ?